# How do I remove divisions recursively with for() loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've created a columnar folder navigator, which — for the most part — works. However, if the user chooses to move backwards (or to the left) and select an earlier folder, I need all the levels that have been previously navigated to be removed.

I can do it for the first level of navigation, but for the life of me, I cannot get the code to remove any of the levels beyond that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var folders = new Object();
    var hierarchy = new Array();
    var levels = new Object();
    var id;
    var index;
    var container = 325;
    levels.index = 1;
    folders.chosen = (folders.chosen == null) ? 0 : folders.chosen;
    $(".folders-hierarchy").delegate('li a', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr("data-folder");
        levels.chosen = $(this).closest('ul').attr("data-levels");
        folders.chosen = id;

        index = hierarchy.indexOf(levels.chosen);
        if (index == -1) {
            hierarchy.push(levels.chosen);
        }
        if (levels.chosen < levels.index) {
            hierarchy.splice(index, hierarchy.length);
            for (var i=levels.chosen;i<levels.index;i++) {
                $('[data-levels="' + i + '"]').parent().remove();
            }
            levels.index = 1;
        } else {
            levels.index++;
        }

        $(".container-folders").css('width', (container = (container+325)) + 'px');
        $("div.container-folders").scrollLeft(325);
        get_folders_hierarchy(folders);
    })
    function get_folders_hierarchy (folders) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "folders/jq_get_folders_hierarchy/" + folders.chosen,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (element) {
                $("div.container-folders").append('<div class="container-folder"><ul id="folders-hierarchy-' + folders.chosen + '" data-levels="' + levels.index + '">');
                if (element!=null) {
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        $("#folders-hierarchy-" + folders.chosen).append('<li><input type="radio" value="' + element[i].child + '" name="folders[]" /><a href="#link" data-folder="' + element[i].child + '">' + element[i].name + '</a></li>');
                        if (i==(element.length)-1) {
                            folders.chosen = element[i].parent;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#folders-hierarchy-" + folders.chosen).append('<li><input type="radio" value="' + folders.chosen + '" name="folders[]" />Choose this Folder</li>');
                }
                $("div.container-folders").append('</ul></div>');
            }
        });
    }
    get_folders_hierarchy(folders);
});
```

The weirdness appears to be happening in the for() loop, where I've attempted to make the iterator start at the selected level, but it is instead doing almost the complete opposite.

I know that all of the various variables are returning the expected values. But having tried every permutation I can think of, nothing works.

While it might not be entirely helpful, I've created [an example of the entire code](http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/czUbZ/). But since the code relies on JSON data being dynamically loaded, it's not going to work without a lot of modifications.

Comment: you can simulate json on a fiddle by setting a specific url and setting your own data to simulate expected return. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But I'd have to get that data out of the database, which would mean making some changes to several class methods, running them, grabbing code, changing IDs .. rinse and repeat for each folder and all their subordinate folders.